# how to set elements to scroll except `overflow`?

Tags: javascript

I was reading  the description of Element.scrollLeft on MDN.

> If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow), scrollLeft is set to 0.

so my question is 
**Are there other properties that can set elements to scroll except `overflow`？**

Comment: To scroll horizontally, only use 'scrollLeft' property.

Answer (score 0):

You should use scrollLeft property.

Plz refer to a demo page below.

https://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/wjna1ee7/

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var elRunner =  document.getElementById("runner");

elRunner.addEventListener("click", function() {
  elmnt.scrollLeft += 100;
},false);
```